# I keep getting fake users registrations

Tags: plugins, members

I  have a huge amount of new fake users on my website everyday, more than 100 per days.

As I did some researches before posting here, I saw that a captcha could help it. So after my hoster informed me that my website was under Brute Force attacks, I downloaded a plugin that I added to my registration form.

My hoster also gave me advices on downloading the "Limit login attempts" plugin.

So far, for my fake members issues, I have "SI Captcha Anti-Spam", "Limite login attempts", "Wordfence Security", "Akismet" and eventually "Jetpack" plugins. Even though I have all of these plugins installed, things didn't change, and I still get a hundred of new fake members every days.

What would you guys advice me to get rid of it ?

Comment: your site might have another loop whole from where fake registrations are getting in. Try checking active plugins and theme files. also you could use a plugin like "IPBlock" which will help you identifying the fakes.

Comment: What do you mean checking plugins and theme files ? I think IPBlock does the same as "Limit login attempts" plugin.

Comment: if someone finds a loop-hole and attacks on your site, they could probably edit your files, so if there is anything harmful code then it will lead to hack your site continuously unless you check / correct / replace those files.